# Conditional removal of elements from SortedSet<SortedSet<int>>

Tags: c#

During processing of each itemset (of type `SortedSet<int>`, called `Itemset`) in `SortedSet<Itemset> ItemsetCollection1`, it is added to another collection, say `ItemsetCollection2`. The requirement is that those itemsets that have been added to `ItemsetCollection2`, must be removed from the former. I am using `RemoveWhere`, whose predicate checks for the existence of the itemset in the latter collection and remove.

```
Itemset i = new Itemset(){1,2};
Itemset j = new Itemset(){2};
Itemset k = new Itemset(){3};
ic1.Add(i);
ic1.Add(j);
ic2.Add(i);
ic2.Add(k);
ic1.RemoveWhere(x => ic2.Any(it => it.Count == x.Count()
                          && it.All(ti => x.Any(tti => ti == tti))));
```

The predicate is working fine. However, the removal of itemsets is failing, i.e the collection `ic1` still has two itemsets in it, when the itemset `i` common to both collections should have been removed from `ic1`. Also, I tried using `ExceptWith` as this is essentially a set difference operation, which is failing too(Although, `ExceptWith` works fine for `Itemset`). Is there any problem with the way the `RemoveWhere` is being used? Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: What means "failing"? Any exception? Unepexted results?

Comment: No exceptions. Although there are itemsets common to both the collections, the function isn't removing them.

Comment: This is where a [mcve] would make it a lot easier to help you. We don't know what any of these collections look like at the moment. (I'd also say that using variable names of `it`, `tti` and `ti` all in the same statement is a bit confusing.)

Comment: Edited. More details regarding the contents of the collection and what exactly is failing has been added.

Comment: What is the decleration of `Itemset`? You can't create a `SortedSet<SortedSet<int>>` because `SortedSet<int>` doesn't implement `IComparable`.

Comment: After I fix the errors, it seems to work fine. Perhaps your `IComparable` is wrong? For your predicate, consider `SetEquals`.

Comment: `IComparable` has been implemented in SortedSet<int>. How have you performed the comparison?